# Javascript will set iframe height to manually given string but not to variable

Tags: javascript, iframe, height

I've got a function that I can't get to work. I've searched for the same problem all over stackoverflow but didn't find any solution...

So this is a code snippet from my index.php. I've got an iframe with news/index.php in it.

```
<div id="hirek1">
    <iframe id="newsframe" src="news/index.php"></iframe>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="mutato.js">milyenmagas();</script>
```

And this is is news/index.php. Its content is a php code, whose output height changes dynamically depending on the lenght of the news in it:

```
<div id="hirekmagassag"><!--content--></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="mutato.js">milyenmagas();</script>
```

The function (of mutato.js):

```
function milyenmagas()
{
    if(document.getElementById('hirekmagassag') != null)
        var divmag = document.getElementById('hirekmagassag').offsetHeight;
        var framemag = (divmag + 10 + 'px');
    if(document.getElementById('hirek1') != null)
        var iframe = document.getElementById('hirek1').getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];
    if(document.getElementById('hirek1') != null)
        iframe.height = framemag;
    if(document.getElementById('hirek1') != null)
        iframe.style.height = framemag;
setTimeout('milyenmagas();', 1000);
}
```

So the point of the function would be to set my iFrame's height equal (+10 pixels for avoiding the scrollbar) to the content's height in it. As you can see above, the function is called after both divs, and since they are called two times (once in each file), the ifs are for sorting out the operations between the two php files.

This does not work for me right now. Except if I change the values of *iframe.height* and *iframe.style.height* from variable *framemag* to for example "500px", then it works perfectly. I don't see what am I doing wrong. Even if I call *alert(framemag);* it throws the right string that should be working perfectly as a style parameter.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
function milyenmagas() {
    var hirekmagassag = document.getElementById('hirekmagassag');

    if (hirekmagassag != null) {
        var divmag = hirekmagassag.offsetHeight;

        var framemag = (divmag + 10) + 'px';

        var hirek1 = document.getElementById('hirek1');
        if (hirek1) {
            var iframe = hirek1.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];
            console.log(framemag)
            iframe.height = framemag;
            iframe.style.height = framemag;
        }

    }
    setTimeout('milyenmagas();', 1000);
}
```

Demo: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/JhbOn6RFMnP2kp8VQwUu?p=preview) - Resize the message div to resize the iframe

Comment: There must be some typo mistakes in my code, this still does not work, not even with manually given strings now :D thanks though